# SPARQL queries concurrently in Java?

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I'm writing a JUnit test that checks the result of about a hundred SPARQL queries.

```
for(String query: queries)
{
 QueryEngineHTTP qe = new QueryEngineHTTP(endpoint, query);
 ResultSet rs = qe.execSelect();
 while(rs.hasNext()) {...}
}
```

To optimize the performance I want to execute some of the queries, but not all of them at once, in parallel. Is there a mechanism in Jena or some other library for this? I could use thread pools but I guess an optimized solution would be better, as it could:

- minimize overhead
- minimize delays by giving all the queries to the server at once in case such a protocol exists
- specify a maximal amount of concurrent queries *per endpoint*, so that if I have 50 queries for DBpedia and 50 for LinkedGeoData, it would run 5 of each at once
- approximate the run time of queries so that it could start the faster ones first
- determine which query order is best for the SPARQL endpoint cache

Comment: Have you taken a look at google-guava libraries? They have a pretty robust extension to the Java Futures API. I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks! But if I understand it correctly it is an extension to general concurrency and not specific to SPARQL?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at an open source tool I developed as part of my job and which my company released under the BSD license called quite simply [SPARQL Query Benchmarker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sparql-query-bm/)

It doesn't have all the features you are looking for but it uses Jena and has some capability to do concurrent querying leveraging the Java concurrency framework so should provide you some  useful code to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely be taking a look at it!